# Coding with webkitTransitionEnd

Tags: jquery, events, ios, mobile-safari

I am coding a web app (for iPad) that uses the event `webkitTransitionEnd`.

I want to call back a function when the **second** transition is ended. The reason why there are two transitions is because one has a `-webkit-transition-delay` property so they two animations don't end at the same time. Since this is a series of animation, I want to call the function only when the second transition is finished.

My current (stupid) workaround is to bind the event inside an event, which looks something like this in jQuery.

```
$(this).bind('webkitTransitionEnd', function(){
   $(this).bind('webkitTransitionEnd', function(){
      \*some code here*\
      $(this).unbind();
   });
   $(this).unbind();
});
```

This works but it is not usable when there are more animations. Say if I want call back a function after 50 animations which ends at different time.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by you have two transitions? There should only be 1 transition per element allowed at a time.

Comment: @Ken: probably by firing off two animations in parallel, for example, to animate two divs side by side at the same time.

Comment: PS use $(this).one() instead of bind if you want to remove the event after it has fired.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested but should give you a good idea.

```
function waitOnTransition(elem, endIndex, callback){
    var transitionIndex = 0;
    $(elem).on('webkitTransitionEnd', function(){
        if(transitionIndex == endIndex){
            callback();
        }else{
            transitionIndex++;
        }
    });
}
waitOnTransition('#elemID', 3, function(){
   //do stuff
});
```

You could also do it with curry

```
function makeTransitionEnd(endIndex){
    var endIndex = endIndex;
    var out = function(elem, callback){
        var transitionIndex = 0;
        $(elem).on('webkitTransitionEnd', function(){
            if(transitionIndex == endIndex){
                callback();
            }else{
                transitionIndex++;
            }
        });
    });
    return out;
}

//make curry
var waitForThreeEnds = makeTransitionEnd(3);
waitForThreeEnds('#elemID', function(){
    //do stuff
});
```